# Java: ClassCastException; Same ClassLoader?

Tags: java, classloader, classcastexception, bukkit

I am having troubles with casting, and I cannot figure it out. According to my research, what causes a `ClassCastException` when you cast a superclass to your class, the reason is they both use different Class Loaders.

I did a simple `System.out.println()` to check if the class loaders are different, but they both print out the same result, `@11cb01a`.

To get to the point on what I'm trying to accomplish, what I am attempting is creating a simple API for myself to make minigames with (I am using the Bukkit API) and I have found errors at two locations of having a `ClassCastException`. First off, I have two classes, the `ArenaBase` and `ArenaManagerBase`. I have a class called `ArenaManager` that extends `ArenaManagerBase`, and `Arena` that extends `ArenaBase`.

When I get my error for a `ClassCastException` for `ArenaManager`, it's from calling `ArenaManager.getInstance()` and casting `(ArenaManager)` to it. When it first starts, I initialize my `ArenaManager`.

```
ArenaManager.init(this);
```

Then, inside of the init I call a few things.

```
public static void init(JavaPlugin instance) {
    am = new ArenaManagerBase(); // What is returned when calling getInstance()
    am.plugin = instance;
    am.ac = new ArenaConfigBase(am.plugin);
    am.init(); // Separate initializer for any subclass that might need it.
}
```

The part that throws the error is this:

```
ArenaManager am = (ArenaManager) ArenaManager.getInstance();
```

So just from this, I have a class that I am trying to cast to that is a superclass of the other. They both seemingly have the same `ClassLoader`. What am I doing wrong, and how could I fix it?

**Edit:**
Here's the stacktrace. It's weird, because at the top it says `null` and then at the bottom it contemplates a `CastClassException`.

```
[18:36:10 ERROR]: null
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'cast
ledefend' in plugin DefendTheCastle vAlpha
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:46) ~[cra
ftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:17
5) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServe
r.java:683) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerCon
nection.java:952) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java
:814) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java
:28) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.PacketPlayInChat.handle(PacketPlayInChat
.java:47) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.NetworkManager.a(NetworkManager.java:146
) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.ServerConnection.c(SourceFile:134) [craf
tbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.MinecraftServer.u(MinecraftServer.java:6
55) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.DedicatedServer.u(DedicatedServer.java:2
50) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.MinecraftServer.t(MinecraftServer.java:5
45) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java
:457) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:6
17) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: me.codermusgrove.arenaapi.ArenaManagerB
ase cannot be cast to me.valdeon.defendthecastle.arena.ArenaManager
        at me.valdeon.defendthecastle.cmd.CmdCreateArena.onCommand(CmdCreateAren
a.java:27) ~[?:?]
        at me.valdeon.defendthecastle.cmd.BaseCommand.onCommand(BaseCommand.java
:30) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44) ~[cra
ftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
        ... 13 more
```

Comment: Can you put the stacktrace?

Comment: Sorry about that, I have added the stacktrace.

Comment: example: `String extends Object`. But you can't cast `(String) new Object()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An instance of a child class can be referred to using a parent type variable. But you cannot do the  reverse. Although, you can bypass the compiler error checking by having an explicit cast like - `(ArenaManager) ArenaManager.getInstance()`, it will eventually fail at runtime with a CCE.

`ArenaManagerBase` is the parent and `ArenaManager` is the child in your case. The instance that you have is of the parent (i.e. `new ArenaManagerBase()`), and you are trying to cast it the child.

Comment: I don't understand what you are referring to. I have inside of the `ArenaManagerBase` a method getInstance() that returns an `ArenaManagerBase`, and `ArenaManager` extends `ArenaManagerBase`, therefore, shouldn't I be able to cast `ArenaManager` to `ArenaManagerBase`?

Comment: Look at the update, which is equivalent to what @njzk2 has on comments.